# Market basket analysis performance

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, market-basket-analysis

I am having problem with Market Basket Analysis, my code to get frequent product set at a min of 1% is taking for ever in running. Below is the script:

```
frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.01, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift")
rules.sort_values('confidence', ascending = False, inplace = True)
rules.head(10)
```

Please how do i correct this for it to be faster.

Regards,

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you an answer any faster. It's also somewhat impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking for free help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe i am stupid, but i have no idea of what is the apriori function or the association_rules one (comes from which library?, pandas? I am not going to look for it to know :D because it is not my job.).